# What happen at OS level when to want to write something into file?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, operating-system

What happen at OS level when to want to write something into file ? Any OS is fine but I am familiar with Linux so if somebody give me answer in Linux that would be great.

I know few things that will happen when we open a file for writing in C below is my rough code.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w+");
fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
```

- C will call library function write().
- write() library function will call system call write().
- 128 interrupt number will be called and execution enters in to kernel mode.
- will pass system call number in eax register.
- will pass argument for write call in ebx,ecx, etc register.
- ??? Now I want to know how it will resolve the file path , how it write to the file , Any disk scheduler involvement (Linus Elevator, Anticipatory Scheduler, CFS Scheduler etc ), Any DMA involvement or any other if I am missing something???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next, the `sys_write` kernel function is called. Go download  a copy of the [Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/) source, and have a look at it.  You're looking for `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(write...` in `fs/read_write.c`.

`sys_write` will call `fdget` to basically get a `struct file*` pointer, and call `vfs_write` (in the same file).

Remember that `write` is a *very* generic syscall, that allows you to write data to any open file descriptor (which may not even be a file on disk, at all).  In the `struct file*` is a pointer (`f_op`) to a number of function pointers. Since a "file" is a totally generic thing, these function pointers are what know how to do the actual writing, depending on the type of file. This provides a sort of "polymorphism", but in plain C code. So `vfs_write` will call `file->f_op->write()`.

These calls will make their way down to the filesystem layer (in the `fs/` directory). So again, it depends on what filesystem you have mounted (e.g. `ext3`, `nfs`, etc.)

Eventually they will make their way down to the block device layer, which is where raw reads/writes of block data to real hardware is done. Again, it depends on the device you have attached (e.g. PATA, SATA/SCSI, RAID, USB, network...)

The device-driver is where the *actual* communication with hardware will take place. This is where any DMA or memory-mapped I/O will occur.

This would probably be best described by a [good book](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=linux%20kernel&sprefix=linux+kerne%2Caps&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Alinux%20kernel).

Comment: thanks. Is there any documentation available on what happen in this function. or can describe more about sys_write kernel function ?

Comment: Do you know is there involvement of DMA or memory-mapped I/O while writing to the file ?

Comment: Of course there is, eventually. To write to a file on a disk, you need to send the disk ATA commands (or whatever type of controller it uses).

Comment: Electrons will move, switches will open and close .. how much detail are you after?